# Proving Continuity of Multivariable Limits at (x,y) = (0,0) for an algebraic function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

This is my first post on Stack Exchange, if I am violating any posting rules, I will gladly edit my post according to the required parameters.

The question I have says for (x, y) $\neq$ (0, 0) $$f(x, y) = \frac{x^3}{x^3 + y^2 - 2x}$$
Show that for f(0, 0) = 0, f(x, y) is not continuous.

Using double limit and the substitution $my^2 = x^3$, I seem to be able to show the function is continuous.

The only way to show the limit does not equal zero seems to be a $my^2 = x^3 - 2x$ substitution and then using double limit again OR using a $mx^3 = y^2 - 2x$ substitution and then cancelling the $x^3$ in the numerator and denominator. Both these methods give different limits, but both having the arbitrary constant "m".

However, both these methods seem sketch to me on different grounds, as in the first one I still have 2 variables after substitution and in the second method, I do not have all variables on one side of the equals sign. I do not know the significance of these petty discomforts in substitution.

Something I have tried doing is changing the subject of the substitution from y to x in the equation $$my^2 = x^3 - 2x$$

However, this has proved to be more difficult than I originally expected. I still think changing the subject in the above equation would give a conclusive answer to what the limit is.

Comment: you have $f(0,y)=0$ and $f(x,\sqrt{2x})=1$ so not continuous.

Comment: @zwim I don't understand how you got y = $\sqrt{2x}$. Can I just substitute "y" for any expression of "x" to prove discontinuity? I have only been doing this for like a month so I'm sorry if this is common knowledge.

Comment: Yes, as long as $y\to 0$ you can substitute what you want for $y$. You only need a counter example, so it's ok to choose some expression.

Comment: @zwim Thanks a lot for the clarification man, how do I "accept answer" or close the question? Also if you can help me out further, is there any way for me to use this website better than I did for this question? Formatting or Tags or what parts of a question should be clarified better, anything helps.

Comment: @TarunMahajan For you to accept an answer a user must first post one. zwim answered your post in the comment section (which is discouraged on the site) but the website doesn't allow a user to accept a comment under the original post as an answer. If zwim won't post an answer you can even post one yourself and accept it. This will remove your post from the "unanswered question" list.